# How to associate Python scripts with active virtualenv?

Tags: python, windows, virtualenv, file-association

After I activate specific virtualenv I'd like to have Python scripts, which I run using only their name (`script.py`), be executed using Python interpreter from virtualenv. How to do this?

It's a followup to the [Why doesn't virtualenv on Windows associate .py/.pyw/.pyo/.pyc files with virtualenv's version of Python executables?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4879624/) question.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to great work of [Vinay Sajip](https://bitbucket.org/vinay.sajip), creator of [Python Launcher](https://bitbucket.org/pypa/pylauncher) (also called pylauncher) and this [commit](https://bitbucket.org/pypa/pylauncher/commits/87d41c5a8f0fef5ef22f09570903e7aa4c850e96) made by [Paul Moore](https://bitbucket.org/pmoore) we can [enjoy](https://bitbucket.org/pypa/pylauncher/downloads) running Python scripts in the context of active virtualenv now! This feature is [planned](http://bugs.python.org/issue17010#msg191062) to be included in Python Launcher bundled with Python 3.4.