# Running Python script from command line opens script in the default text editor instead of executing script

Tags: python, windows, command-line, file-association

I have files with `.py` extension associated with Python interpreter. However when I type name of such a file at the command line and press `ENTER` the file is being opened in the default text editor (Notepad++) instead of being run with the associated Python interpreter. Why?

```
Z:\1>where python
c:\Program Files\Python\2.7\python.exe

Z:\1>reg query HKCR\.py /ve

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.py
    (Default)    REG_SZ    Python.File


Z:\1>reg query HKCR\Python.File\shell\open\command /ve

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.File\shell\open\command
    (Default)    REG_SZ    c:\Program Files\Python\2.7\python.exe "%1" %*


Z:\1>echo %PATHEXT%
.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC;.PY;.PYW

Z:\1>type a.py
from __future__ import print_function; import sys; print(sys.executable); print(sys.version)
Z:\1>a.py    <--- this opens a.py in the default text editor
```

I'm on Windows Vista x64 using `Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2012, 23:24:47) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32`

UPDATE

After deleting `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Unknown\shell\notepad++\command` key (I created this key in the past in my quest to associate files without extension with Notepad++ - see [How to set the default program for opening files without an extension in Windows?](https://superuser.com/q/13653/664)) which had value of `C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++ %1` I get this error:

> This file does not have a program associated with it for performing
>   this action. Create an association in the Set Associations control
>   panel.

UPDATE 2

To display all registry keys used normally by system to find out what program is associated with `.py` extension I run the following batch file (`python_assoc.query.bat`):

```
@echo off
if "%~1" == "details" (
    set keypath=HKLM\Software\Classes
    echo ----- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE -----
    call :query
    set keypath=HKCU\Software\Classes
    echo.
    echo ----- HKEY_CURRENT_USER -----
    call :query
) else (
    set keypath=HKCR
    echo ----- HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT -----
    call :query
)   
goto end

:query
reg query %keypath%\.py /ve
reg query %keypath%\.pyw /ve
reg query %keypath%\.pyc /ve
reg query %keypath%\.pyo /ve

reg query %keypath%\Python.File\shell\open\command /ve
reg query %keypath%\Python.NoConFile\shell\open\command /ve
reg query %keypath%\Python.CompiledFile\shell\open\command /ve
goto :eof

:end
set keypath=
```

OUTPUT

```
Z:\1>python_assoc.query.bat details
----- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE -----

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes\.py
    (Default)    REG_SZ    Python.File
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes\.pyw
    (Default)    REG_SZ    Python.NoConFile
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes\.pyc
    (Default)    REG_SZ    Python.CompiledFile
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes\.pyo
    (Default)    REG_SZ    Python.CompiledFile
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes\Python.File\shell\open\command
    (Default)    REG_SZ    c:\Program Files\Python\2.7\python.exe "%1" %*
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes\Python.NoConFile\shell\open\command
    (Default)    REG_SZ    c:\Program Files\Python\2.7\pythonw.exe "%1" %*
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes\Python.CompiledFile\shell\open\command
    (Default)    REG_SZ    c:\Program Files\Python\2.7\python.exe "%1" %*

----- HKEY_CURRENT_USER -----
ERROR: The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value.
ERROR: The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value.
ERROR: The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value.
ERROR: The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value.
ERROR: The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value.
ERROR: The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value.
ERROR: The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value.
```

I also run Process Monitor (thanks *Maximus*) to see what registry keys are being read when running `a.py` from command line. I have set filter to include only pid of `cmd.exe` used to run `a.py` file and to exclude operations of type `RegCloseKey`.

```
"Operation","Path","Result","Detail"
"RegOpenKey","HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers","NAME NOT FOUND","Desired Access: Query Value"
"RegOpenKey","HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WINDOWS NT\CURRENTVERSION\AppCompatFlags\Custom\a.py","NAME NOT FOUND","Desired Access: Query Value"
"RegOpenKey","HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer","SUCCESS","Desired Access: Query Value"
"RegQueryValue","HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MaximizeApps","NAME NOT FOUND","Length: 144"
"RegOpenKey","HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer","SUCCESS","Desired Access: Query Value"
"RegQueryValue","HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\explorer\MaximizeApps","NAME NOT FOUND","Length: 144"
"RegQueryKey","HKCU\Software\Classes","SUCCESS","Query: Name"
"RegOpenKey","HKCU\Software\Classes\Drive\shellex\FolderExtensions","NAME NOT FOUND","Desired Access: Enumerate Sub Keys"
"RegOpenKey","HKCR\Drive\shellex\FolderExtensions","SUCCESS","Desired Access: Enumerate Sub Keys"
"RegQueryKey","HKCR\Drive\shellex\FolderExtensions","SUCCESS","Query: Name"
"RegOpenKey","HKCU\Software\Classes\Drive\shellex\FolderExtensions","NAME NOT FOUND","Desired Access: Maximum Allowed"
"RegEnumKey","HKCR\Drive\shellex\FolderExtensions","SUCCESS","Index: 0, Name: {fbeb8a05-beee-4442-804e-409d6c4515e9}"
"RegQueryKey","HKCU\Software\Classes","SUCCESS","Query: Name"
"RegOpenKey","HKCU\Software\Classes\Drive\shellex\FolderExtensions\{fbeb8a05-beee-4442-804e-409d6c4515e9}","NAME NOT FOUND","Desired Access: Query Value"
"RegOpenKey","HKCR\Drive\shellex\FolderExtensions\{fbeb8a05-beee-4442-804e-409d6c4515e9}","SUCCESS","Desired Access: Query Value"
"RegQueryKey","HKCR\Drive\shellex\FolderExtensions\{fbeb8a05-beee-4442-804e-409d6c4515e9}","SUCCESS","Query: Name"
"RegOpenKey","HKCU\Software\Classes\Drive\shellex\FolderExtensions\{fbeb8a05-beee-4442-804e-409d6c4515e9}","NAME NOT FOUND","Desired Access: Maximum Allowed"
"RegQueryValue","HKCR\Drive\shellex\FolderExtensions\{fbeb8a05-beee-4442-804e-409d6c4515e9}\DriveMask","SUCCESS","Type: REG_DWORD, Length: 4, Data: 32"
"RegEnumKey","HKCR\Drive\shellex\FolderExtensions","NO MORE ENTRIES","Index: 1, Length: 288"
"RegQueryKey","HKCU\Software\Classes","SUCCESS","Query: Name"
"RegOpenKey","HKCU\Software\Classes\.py","NAME NOT FOUND","Desired Access: Query Value"
"RegOpenKey","HKCR\.py","SUCCESS","Desired Access: Query Value"
"RegQueryKey","HKCR\.py","SUCCESS","Query: Name"
"RegOpenKey","HKCU\Software\Classes\.py","NAME NOT FOUND","Desired Access: Maximum Allowed"
"RegQueryValue","HKCR\.py\(Default)","SUCCESS","Type: REG_SZ, Length: 26, Data: Python.File "
"RegQueryKey","HKCU\Software\Classes","SUCCESS","Query: Name"
"RegOpenKey","HKCU\Software\Classes\.py\OpenWithProgids","NAME NOT FOUND","Desired Access: Read"
"RegOpenKey","HKCR\.py\OpenWithProgids","NAME NOT FOUND","Desired Access: Read"
"RegOpenKey","HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.py\OpenWithProgids","SUCCESS","Desired Access: Read"
"RegQueryKey","HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.py\OpenWithProgids","SUCCESS","Query: Cached, SubKeys: 0, Values: 2"
"RegEnumValue","HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.py\OpenWithProgids","SUCCESS","Index: 0, Length: 220"
"RegQueryKey","HKCU\Software\Classes","SUCCESS","Query: Name"
"RegOpenKey","HKCU\Software\Classes\Python.File","NAME NOT FOUND","Desired Access: Read"
"RegOpenKey","HKCR\Python.File","SUCCESS","Desired Access: Read"
"RegEnumValue","HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.py\OpenWithProgids","SUCCESS","Index: 1, Length: 220"
"RegEnumValue","HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.py\OpenWithProgids","NO MORE ENTRIES","Index: 2, Length: 220"
"RegQueryKey","HKCU\Software\Classes","SUCCESS","Query: Name"
"RegOpenKey","HKCU\Software\Classes\.py","NAME NOT FOUND","Desired Access: Read"
"RegOpenKey","HKCR\.py","SUCCESS","Desired Access: Read"
"RegOpenKey","HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.py","SUCCESS","Desired Access: Read"
"RegOpenKey","HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.py","SUCCESS","Desired Access: Read"
"RegOpenKey","HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.py\UserChoice","NAME NOT FOUND","Desired Access: Query Value"
"RegQueryKey","HKCU\Software\Classes","SUCCESS","Query: Name"
"RegOpenKey","HKCU\Software\Classes\Python.File ","NAME NOT FOUND","Desired Access: Read"
"RegOpenKey","HKCR\Python.File ","NAME NOT FOUND","Desired Access: Read"
"RegQueryKey","HKCU\Software\Classes","SUCCESS","Query: Name"
"RegOpenKey","HKCU\Software\Classes\.py","NAME NOT FOUND","Desired Access: Read"
"RegOpenKey","HKCR\.py","SUCCESS","Desired Access: Read"
"RegQueryKey","HKCR\.py","SUCCESS","Query: Name"
"RegOpenKey","HKCU\Software\Classes\.py\shell","NAME NOT FOUND","Desired Access: Read"
"RegOpenKey","HKCR\.py\shell","NAME NOT FOUND","Desired Access: Read"
"RegQueryKey","HKCU\Software\Classes","SUCCESS","Query: Name"
"RegOpenKey","HKCU\Software\Classes\.py","NAME NOT FOUND","Desired Access: Read"
"RegOpenKey","HKCR\.py","SUCCESS","Desired Access: Read"
"RegQueryKey","HKCU\Software\Classes","SUCCESS","Query: Name"
"RegOpenKey","HKCU\Software\Classes\Unknown","NAME NOT FOUND","Desired Access: Read"
"RegOpenKey","HKCR\Unknown","NAME NOT FOUND","Desired Access: Read"
"RegQueryKey","HKCU\Software\Classes","SUCCESS","Query: Name"
"RegOpenKey","HKCU\Software\Classes\SystemFileAssociations\.py","NAME NOT FOUND","Desired Access: Read"
"RegOpenKey","HKCR\SystemFileAssociations\.py","NAME NOT FOUND","Desired Access: Read"
"RegQueryKey","HKCU\Software\Classes","SUCCESS","Query: Name"
"RegOpenKey","HKCU\Software\Classes\.py","NAME NOT FOUND","Desired Access: Query Value"
"RegOpenKey","HKCR\.py","SUCCESS","Desired Access: Query Value"
"RegQueryKey","HKCR\.py","SUCCESS","Query: Name"
"RegOpenKey","HKCU\Software\Classes\.py","NAME NOT FOUND","Desired Access: Maximum Allowed"
"RegQueryValue","HKCR\.py\PerceivedType","NAME NOT FOUND","Length: 144"
"RegQueryKey","HKCU\Software\Classes","SUCCESS","Query: Name"
"RegOpenKey","HKCU\Software\Classes\SystemFileAssociations\.py","NAME NOT FOUND","Desired Access: Query Value"
"RegOpenKey","HKCR\SystemFileAssociations\.py","NAME NOT FOUND","Desired Access: Query Value"
"RegQueryKey","HKCU\Software\Classes","SUCCESS","Query: Name"
"RegOpenKey","HKCU\Software\Classes\*","SUCCESS","Desired Access: Read"
"RegQueryKey","HKCU\Software\Classes\*","SUCCESS","Query: Name"
"RegOpenKey","HKCU\Software\Classes\*\shell","NAME NOT FOUND","Desired Access: Read"
"RegOpenKey","HKCR\*\shell","SUCCESS","Desired Access: Read"
"RegQueryKey","HKCR\*\shell","SUCCESS","Query: Name"
"RegOpenKey","HKCU\Software\Classes\*\shell","NAME NOT FOUND","Desired Access: Maximum Allowed"
"RegQueryValue","HKCR\*\shell\(Default)","NAME NOT FOUND","Length: 144"
"RegQueryKey","HKCR\*\shell","SUCCESS","Query: Name"
"RegOpenKey","HKCU\Software\Classes\*\shell\open","NAME NOT FOUND","Desired Access: Read"
"RegOpenKey","HKCR\*\shell\open","NAME NOT FOUND","Desired Access: Read"
"RegQueryKey","HKCU\Software\Classes","SUCCESS","Query: Name"
"RegOpenKey","HKCU\Software\Classes\AllFilesystemObjects","NAME NOT FOUND","Desired Access: Read"
"RegOpenKey","HKCR\AllFilesystemObjects","SUCCESS","Desired Access: Read"
"RegQueryKey","HKCR\AllFilesystemObjects","SUCCESS","Query: Name"
"RegOpenKey","HKCU\Software\Classes\AllFilesystemObjects\shell","NAME NOT FOUND","Desired Access: Read"
"RegOpenKey","HKCR\AllFilesystemObjects\shell","NAME NOT FOUND","Desired Access: Read"
"RegOpenKey","HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\SideBySide","SUCCESS","Desired Access: Read"
"RegQueryValue","HKLM\COMPONENTS\PreferExternalManifest","NAME NOT FOUND","Length: 20"
"RegOpenKey","HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\SideBySide\AssemblyStorageRoots","REPARSE","Desired Access: Enumerate Sub Keys"
"RegOpenKey","HKLM\COMPONENTS\AssemblyStorageRoots","NAME NOT FOUND","Desired Access: Enumerate Sub Keys"
"RegOpenKey","HKLM\Software\Microsoft\DirectUI","NAME NOT FOUND","Desired Access: Read"
"RegOpenKey","HKLM\Software\Microsoft\CTF\TIP\{0000897b-83df-4b96-be07-0fb58b01c4a4}\LanguageProfile\0x00000000\{0001bea3-ed56-483d-a2e2-aeae25577436}","SUCCESS","Desired Access: Read"
"RegQueryValue","HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\CTF\TIP\{0000897b-83df-4b96-be07-0fb58b01c4a4}\LanguageProfile\0x00000000\{0001bea3-ed56-483d-a2e2-aeae25577436}\Enable","SUCCESS","Type: REG_DWORD, Length: 4, Data: 1"
"RegOpenKey","HKCU","SUCCESS","Desired Access: Read"
"RegOpenKey","HKCU\Keyboard Layout\Toggle","SUCCESS","Desired Access: Read"
"RegQueryValue","HKCU\Keyboard Layout\Toggle\Language Hotkey","SUCCESS","Type: REG_SZ, Length: 4, Data: 3"
"RegQueryValue","HKCU\Keyboard Layout\Toggle\Layout Hotkey","SUCCESS","Type: REG_SZ, Length: 4, Data: 3"
"RegOpenKey","HKCU","SUCCESS","Desired Access: Read"
"RegOpenKey","HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\CTF\LangBarAddIn","NAME NOT FOUND","Desired Access: Read"
"RegOpenKey","HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\CTF\LangBarAddIn","NAME NOT FOUND","Desired Access: Read"
"RegOpenKey","HKCU","SUCCESS","Desired Access: Read"
"RegOpenKey","HKCU\Software\Microsoft\CTF\DirectSwitchHotkeys","SUCCESS","Desired Access: Read"
"RegEnumKey","HKCU\Software\Microsoft\CTF\DirectSwitchHotkeys","NO MORE ENTRIES","Index: 0, Length: 288"
"RegOpenKey","HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\CTF\KnownClasses","NAME NOT FOUND","Desired Access: Read"
"RegOpenKey","HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\CTF\KnownClasses","NAME NOT FOUND","Desired Access: Read"
"RegOpenKey","HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\FontSubstitutes","SUCCESS","Desired Access: Read"
"RegQueryValue","HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WINDOWS NT\CURRENTVERSION\FontSubstitutes\Segoe UI","NAME NOT FOUND","Length: 144"
"RegOpenKey","HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\CTF\KnownClasses","NAME NOT FOUND","Desired Access: Read"
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Making Python scripts run on Windows without specifying ".py" extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9037346/making-python-scripts-run-on-windows-without-specifying-py-extension)

Comment: @bgporter It's not duplicate of that question. I'm not talking about running Python script without writing its extension.

Comment: Check and recreate if necessary your Python file [associations](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5586761/355230).

Comment: @Piotr -- did you actually read the link, or just look at the title? It shows you how to associate .py files with the python interpreter.

Comment: @bgporter Have you noticed I've even **edited** that question in the past? You clearly have no clue what the problem I'm describing here is.

Comment: @martineau As you can see from the output of `reg query...` commands I cited in my question, my associations are set properly.

Comment: you could try to install [pylauncher](https://bitbucket.org/vinay.sajip/pylauncher). It registers itself to run python files. It should get you working settings

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Thanks for suggestion (I'm well aware of this app) but I'd like to know what's going on here.

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost: If it fixes the issue you'll know at what settings you should look more closely. If it doesn't you'll know to look somewhere else. See [pylauncher screencast](http://www.red-dove.com/screencasts/launcher/launcher.html)

Comment: Since all else has failed, just reinstall Python.

Comment: Have you tried running `assoc .PY=Python.File` and `ftype Python.File=c:\Program Files\Python\2.7\python.exe "%1" %*` in an elevated console?

Comment: You could also check the user settings in `HKCU\Software\Classes`.

Comment: @eryksun This fixed the problem - please write it as an answer. However I still don't know what was broken as the output from my batch file is identical to the one before running `assoc` and `ftype`. I thought my batch file displays all registry keys which `assoc` and `ftype` could possibly modify... I guess I should inspect what registry keys are being written by these programs using *Process Monitor*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, I'd make sure the association isn't being overridden by settings for the current user:

- `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.py\UserChoice`
- `HKCU\Software\Classes\.py`
- `HKCU\Software\Classes\Python.File`

However, as I read the Process Monitor output in your update, it doesn't appear that any of these `HKCU` keys are defined on your system.

My next step would be to run the following in an elevated `cmd` console:

```
> assoc .PY=Python.File
> ftype Python.File=c:\Program Files\Python\2.7\python.exe "%1" %*
```

As far as I know, this sets the system association in `HKLM\Software\Classes` and does nothing else. Based on the information in your question, it seems this was already set correctly. So I don't know what either `assoc` or `ftype` did to fix the problem.

Comment: Maybe the problem had something to do with 32bit/64bit *mismatch*. Although I made sure `cmd.exe` I was running was 64bit, when I run `python` later to report its exact version in my question the version information ended with `on win32` text. I can't reproduce it now - there's no `on win32` suffix any more. Additionally when looking at registry keys being modified by `ftype` command I see it modifies `Wow6432Node` counterparts, too. Maybe there was something wrong with `Wow6432Node` version of registry keys and `ftype` fixed this. However I remember 32bit keys were the same as 64bit ones...

Answer (score 2):

I've been struggling with this problem for a while, same as Piotr. The suggestion by eriksyn led me to a working system.

Since Notepad2 was always opening my "I-want-to-run-this" invocations, it must be that I have something associating all files with Notepad2, and now I knew where to look (I tried running Process Monitor previously, but the output was too voluminous).

I have `.py` entries with Notepad2 contents in  `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts` in my registry. I assume either Notepad2 added these itself, or I did this somehow when configuring things. In particular:

```
> reg query HKCU\Software\...\Explorer\FileExts\.py\UserChoice
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\...\Explorer\FileExts\.py\UserChoice
    Progid    REG_SZ    Applications\Notepad2.exe
```

With this registry key and value, trying to run a Python script just opens Notepad2.

Without this registry key, my Python scripts actually execute, no longer requiring me to type "python <script>" to run them.

I'm happy. Thanks, Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

May be this may help (make "open" as default verb)?

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.File\shell]
@="open"
```

or this (take into account quotas around `python.exe` path)?

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.File\shell\open]
@="Open"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.File\shell\open\command]
@="\"c:\\Program Files\\Python\\2.7\\python.exe\" \"%1\" %*"
```

Comment: Last chance ;) Run Process Monitor and try to run `a` in cmd prompt. Analyze log, I believe it may give you a hint

Comment: Manually tell python to run my script from registry: "C:\Python27\python.exe" "C:\Python27\tpt.py" "%1"`

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just do this the GUI way?

"Open with..." -> browse -> python.exe and tick "always use this program..."

Comment: When I choose *Open with...* I get the same error as shown in my update. See [Choose Default Program dialog does not show up after choosing Open with entry in context menu](http://superuser.com/questions/69193/)