# How to prevent command prompt ( windows ) from opening file when typing command?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I download source code of my app from google appengine  using this command in cmd:

```
appcfg.py download_app -A <your_app_id> -V <your_app_version> <output-dir>
```

But, instead of running the command, it opens the file "appcfg.py". So I don't know what to do now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like python files are associated with an editor instead of with the python interpreter.
If so you'll have to change the associations for .py files (found in folder options), or call the python interpreter:

```
 C:\path\to\python appcfg.py download_app -A -V
```

Comment: Thanks, but it still opens the "appcfg.py" in the text editor when I enter the command.

Comment: Ah, I've just found out the answer in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13326181/running-python-script-from-command-line-opens-script-in-the-default-text-editor

Just right click on the .py file and choose this: "Open with..." -> browse -> python.exe and tick "always use this program..." Then everything's fine! :)

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant by changing the association :)