# Unable to execute python file on php on local server with shell_exec

Tags: php, python-3.x, xampp, shell-exec

im trying to execute .py file on php. Ive installed my python through anaconda, 3.7

ive tried to use shell_exec command but it doesnt execute the output from .py file. its just open the .py file in sublime.

```py
#the output should be test
print ("test")
```

the .py file saved test.py

```php
<?php
$command = escapeshellcmd('test.py');
$output = shell_exec($command);
echo $output;
?>
```

the .php file saved as cb.php

i put them on the same file named test, in htdoc.  i type http://localhost/test/cb.php to run the php file on the browser. I expect the .py code should be executed and the php file should output "test" but the test.py file just opened on sublime text which is my default text editor.

Comment: Missing info: PATH, execution bit, stderr, errno.

Comment: there are no error, everything seems fine. when i execute the .php file its just blank and open the .py file

Comment: If this is on Windows, the script may not be executed unless you also specify the interpreter. Else e.g.: [Running Python script from command line opens script in the default text editor instead of executing script](//stackoverflow.com/q/13326181)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13326181/running-python-script-from-command-line-opens-script-in-the-default-text-editor im sorry but i dont understand any of these. 
i tried this part
> assoc .PY=Python.File
> ftype Python.File=c:\Program Files\Python\2.7\python.exe "%1" %*
this happened:
Access is denied.
Error occurred while processing: PY.

Comment: Why don't you just invoke the script as you would in cmd?

Comment: it works, like a charm, i manually change the default app to open python. it  was sublime then i change it to python.exe

Comment: You could use `shell_exec("python.exe test.py")` rather.

Comment: i was using shell_exec("python test.py" it wasnt work, it wasnt even open the file on sublime. is there any differences