# VSCode: The term 'python' is not recognized...but py works

Tags: python, build, visual-studio-code, automation, vscode-code-runner

I just installed python on VS Code and I can't run any python code using `python` command.

### python command:

Running the code seems to run `python` command by default and it does not recognize it.

When I right click and choose `Run Code` it complains:

`'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file`

Same goes for manually running `python main.py`.

When I open an elevated PowerShell and run `python`, it complains:

```
python : The term 'python' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ python
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (python:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

### py command:

It doesn't try to use `py` command but it recognizes it. **And when I manually call `py main.py`, it works**.

When I manually do `>py main.py` it writes my `Goodbye, World!`

### Question:

How can I make it compile/run in VS Code simply by using the CodeRunner's right-click feature (`Run Code`)?

---

**I already have both Python folder and its Scripts folder in PATH.**

I'm using `VS Code 1.27.2` and I have installed `python 3.7.0` on my machine and have checked its installer checkbox for adding the environment variables automatically. (PATH is ok)

I also installed : `ms-python.python` and `tht13.python` and `formulahendry.code-runner` extensions on the VS Code.

---

This is my `main.py` code:

```
print("Goodbye, World!")
```

Comment: What happens if you call `python main.py`?

Comment: @martineau it says `'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file`

Comment: That sounds like Python isn't installed correctly. This is strange because if `py` works, so should `python`. Have you read [Using Python on Windows](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html)? You may need to manually run one or more command-line utilities to get the registry set up correctly. Although it's a bit dated, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5586761/355230) answer I once wrote for an example of what I am talking about.

Comment: @martineau I found the problem, it needed a restart, but thanks for the useful information

Comment: After installing python, needs to restart both of terminal and VS Code if you already opened them. 
It worked for me without restarting computer.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It turned out that I just had to **restart my computer** after I installed `ms-python.python` and `tht13.python` and `formulahendry.code-runner` extensions on the VS Code and added python's `Scripts` folder in `PATH`.

Now both `py` and `python` commands work from anywhere like `cmd` or `Run Code` in the right click menu.

Comment: jaja thats the solution, only restart the computer

Comment: This did the trick for me too. **If you just downloaded Code Runner you will need to restart and try again!**

Comment: I had to restart VS code after installing the python installer.

Answer (score 5):

Restarting your PC after installing the Python Extension and changing the PATH to include Python and it's scripts folder will help. Worked for me

Answer (score 3):

The Windows installer for Python does not put `python` on your path by default (there's a checkbox during installation to add it). Make sure that you selected an interpreter that's installed by running `Select Interpreter` and choosing the interpreter you want (the extension will find them through the registry).

Comment: in my version of python, it didn't provide that option, it turned out the problem was a restart issue, but thanks for the info

Answer (score 2):

I also had this problem after a fresh Windows reinstallation, vscode didnt recognize the commands like `python` or `pip freeze` in the PS terminal.

After reinstalling python and vscode, I read the tutorial for python for vscode: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial. Creating a new venv worked for me `py -3 -m venv .venv`, then navigate to the venv: `.venv\scripts\activate`. In the new venv all the python commands worked as normal.

Answer (score 1):

If you have already set the path variable, test the same command in a command prompt and see if it works. If it does, just update PowerShell's `path` settings by running the following from your vs code PowerShell terminal:

```
$env:Path = [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("Path","Machine") + ";" +
            [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("Path","User")`
```

This trick can save you a lot of restarts.

Answer (score 1):

If you've tried all the above, and still no luck, click the "Run Python File" in the Code Runner drop-down menu in the top right corner.

[image]

Somehow it stuck at "Run Code" hence the "'python3' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file." message.

Even though I was using keyboard shortcuts to run the code, it still persisted.
Choosing the "Run Python File" unlocked the shortcuts, and all started working properly.

Comment: *'"Run Python File" in the Code Runner drop-down menu* - Code Runner doesn't provide that menu, only the "Run Code" option. "Run Python File" is provided by the Python extension IIRC.

Answer (score 0):

you need to first confirm if python is installed, for that just run python/python3 on terminal/cmd.

If it runs there and it isn't running in VS Code then restart your system in order to get changes reflected.

And if it doesn't run in terminal/cmd as well then first check if python's directories are placed in environment variables.

Answer (score -1):

Add Python path (ex C:\Users\johndoe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39) to the %PATH% env variable

Answer (score -1):

I added PATH and did everything. but it didn't work on Vscode Powershell.
but python was working in windows CMD. So I just **reinstalled** Vscode.

Answer (score -2):

Go to preferences > settings in VS Code, search for "Code" extension and add this line in "settings.json" file:

```json
{
  ...
  "python": "python"
  ...
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Try to install python from Microsoft stores

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).