# I can't run the script and make a virtual environment

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-venv

I'm trying to install a virtual environment in order to work with libraries, but it absolutely does not work

python : The name "python" is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program. Check the spelling of the name, as well as the presence and correctness of the path, and then try again.
line:1 sign:1

- python -m venv scrap
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (python:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows, you need to add Python to your PATH. Try this [How to add Python to PATH](https://www.educative.io/edpresso/how-to-add-python-to-path-variable-in-windows)

And check if Python is installed correctly and restart your PC [on this Question restarting the PC helped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52332554/vscode-the-term-python-is-not-recognized-but-py-works)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the path to your environment variables.

You should go to `Control Panel>System` and `Security>System>Advanced System Settings>Environment Variables`

Then select `edit PATH` and append the path to your `python` executable:

```
C:\Users\{your_user}\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\{your_python_executable}
```