# vsCode won't recognize python installation, but does?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

When I put "`py --list`" in the terminal I get this:

```
Installed Pythons found by C:\Windows\py.exe Launcher for Windows
No Installed Pythons Found!
```

I set my environment variables. I actually got VS Code to run some code I threw together that didn't use any imports, but now that I'm trying to use **any** python commands in the terminal, I'm getting errors. What gives?

python should work, since it **is** finding installations.

Comment: you should make sure the python extension is installed in vsCode. Additionally, you should set the interpreter. Do do this: ctrl + shift + p and then type "Python: Select Interpreter" and add the corresponding path

Comment: hmmm, is it related to this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52332554/vscode-the-term-python-is-not-recognized-but-py-works

Comment: I guess not. I have PATH referencing both python and it's script folder. I guess I can reinstall both py and vs since they are apparently nonfunctional.

Comment: which type of terminal are you using?  Can you run python or the py launcher from a command prompt or powershell session outside of VSCode?

Comment: If you run the following `import sys; print(sys.executable)` in VS Code what do you get?

Comment: cant post full error, but both import and sys.executable throw up errors.

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure that you have installed the python extension and selected the correct python interpreter (`Ctrl+Shift+P` and type **Python: Select Interprete**r).

If this didn't work, you may have to **reinstall python**.

Read the [document about Vscode-Python](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for reply, will reinstalling really help though? I just installed it on this machine yesterday. I should point out that when I go to select interpreter it finds my python path. I am able to compile and run python, but actually using it in terminal in vsCode doesn't work (cmd.exe works fine)

Comment: Can this work if you add `"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Command Prompt",` to your **user settings**?

Answer (score -1):

If you are working on Windows, very often it's all about permissions. Try running your terminal and VSCode as administrator! Worked a lot of times for me, also with other languages.

Comment: Almost certainly unnecessary if apps are installed correctly and very poor security practice.

Comment: True, but it's a quick fix most of the times