# Windows virtualenv not switching python for django

Tags: python, windows, django, virtualenv, django-1.4

I managed to install virtualenv, install django-1.4-alpha-1 via pip install and am trying to start a django with it's `manage.py runserver`

Eventhough I switched with virtualenv via activate (note the prefix in cmd screen bellow) to the right enviroment (where I successfully installed django), `manage.py runserver` still somehow grabs data from my stable not-virtualenv python install.

Stable python (wrong one): `D:\Python26\Scripts`

Right one: `E:\Prace\django-1.4-alpha-1\Scripts`

My PATH doesn't include anything with Python.

Cmd screen:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Files with the .py extension are linked to your default Windows Python installation. One way of using your virtualenv python executable instead is by typing `python manage.py <command>` instead.

Please also see the accepted answer of [a question I posted on this matter before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112749/virtualenv-keeps-loading-global-site-packages-on-windows).

Answer (score 1):

You don't specify which version of virtualenv you're using. Recently, they've made `--no-site-packages` default, but if you're using a version before this change was instituted, you need to specify that switch to prevent the main site-packages from loading in.